# Find Each line of a textfile in another text file using python

Tags: python-2.7

I have 2 text files, 1 which contain keywords in a each line around 75 lines ex. __key25words_ 
Second file contains thousand of lines I want to find a keyword in secondfile if it is present anywhere in second file I want to print that line similar way it should check for all keywords in second file and print if any matches
Note: am able to print a keyword but only when second file starts a line with that key word my script not printing even if keyword exist in middle of line in second file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `file1` contains  keywords and `file2` contains the lines to be compared , 
then this code may help you

```
with  open('file1.txt' , 'r+') as file1 : 
    for keyword in file1.readlines() :
        keyword = keyword.replace('\n' , '')
        print ("Looking for " , keyword , " in file" )
        with  open('file2.txt' , 'r+') as file2:
            for line in file2.readlines():
                if keyword in line: 
                    print(line)
```